# How To get the information at the top of website for which user searched for?

Tags: html, django, web

I am designing a webpage which is also a home page of my website on which I have to put some question and answers, so what I want to do is that for example a user searched a question on google which is on my webpage and then user clicked on my web page so I want to bring  that question at the top of my web page.
(I am using Django framework for building my website in case this info is needed.)
NOTE: Im new on stackoverflow pls forgive if question is not proper

Answer (score -1):

You have to use SSL certificate, so that you will be listed on top of Google search...

Comment: i don't think it helped